# Recovering list saved in textfile as string, turning it back into list

Tags: python, string, list, text-parsing

Newbie question after four hours of research.

I wrote a program that saves formulas in a textfile in string format:

```
['myminus', 'IBM', 'Low', 'myplus', 'IBM', 'Close', 'WMT', 'Low']
```

When I read these formulas from the textfile, however, I am having trouble recovering them in their original form.

When I split the alg string on the '`,`' -- as in `alg.string(',')` -- I get a mess:

```
["['myminus'", " 'IBM'", " 'Low'", " 'myplus'", " 'IBM'", " 'Close'", " 'WMT'", " 'Low']"]
```

How do I take the string in line 3 and translate into a list of string? Especially, how do I get rid of the double quotes?

(They are for later use by a Reverse Polish eval function.)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The language is Python 2.X.

Comment: Pickle or ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 3):

If you have a string, you can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to turn it back into Python data structure:

```
>>> s="['myminus', 'IBM', 'Low', 'myplus', 'IBM', 'Close', 'WMT', 'Low']"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
['myminus', 'IBM', 'Low', 'myplus', 'IBM', 'Close', 'WMT', 'Low']
```

You can also use something like [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to serialize Python data to / from a file.

Here is json:

```
>>> li=['myminus', 'IBM', 'Low', 'myplus', 'IBM', 'Close', 'WMT', 'Low']
>>> 
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(li)
'["myminus", "IBM", "Low", "myplus", "IBM", "Close", "WMT", "Low"]'
>>> s=json.dumps(li)
>>> li2=json.loads(s)
>>> li2
[u'myminus', u'IBM', u'Low', u'myplus', u'IBM', u'Close', u'WMT', u'Low']
```

Pickle:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> s=pickle.dumps(li)
>>> s
"(lp0\nS'myminus'\np1\naS'IBM'\np2\naS'Low'\np3\naS'myplus'\np4\nag2\naS'Close'\np5\naS'WMT'\np6\nag3\na."
>>> pickle.loads(s)
['myminus', 'IBM', 'Low', 'myplus', 'IBM', 'Close', 'WMT', 'Low']
```

Finally, if that is the totality of your data, you could just save and recover as csv using the Python [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

li=['myminus', 'IBM', 'Low', 'myplus', 'IBM', 'Close', 'WMT', 'Low']

with open('/tmp/calc.csv', 'w') as fout:
    writer=csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerow(li)

with open('/tmp/calc.csv', 'r') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin)
    data=next(reader)

>>> data
['myminus', 'IBM', 'Low', 'myplus', 'IBM', 'Close', 'WMT', 'Low']
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting JSON or Pickle. That's really the right way to do it here.